# How to query a data attribute value in javascript (no jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a grid made up of `ul's` (the rows) and `li's` (the cells), I wanted to get a specific cell based on the data attribute values of the `ul` and the `li`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(div.grid ul[data-${this.y}] li[data-${this.x}]'_
```

When I searched on MDN, I only found how to retrieve the `html element` based on the `data attribute`, but not it's value.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - also no `jQuery` please.

Comment: you need this ? `document.querySelector('ul[data-y="SOME_ROW_ID"] li[data-x="SOME_COL_ID"]')`

Comment: What is `-${this.y}` do ? Does that evaluate to something?

Comment: are you saying you need data-y, rather than just data? why?

Comment: i'm passing in the value of the variable this.y to the selector

Comment: you know what, document.querySelectorAll('div.grid ul[data="2"] li[data="5"]') works, just need to figure out how to get the variable value in double quotes " " now

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div.grid ul[data="'+this.x+'"] li[data="'+this.y+'"]')` . I'm still not sure how this is `-${this.y}` pure js.

Comment: Yup, this is super helpful, I think I was just getting tripped up with the syntax. ${this.y} is not jQuery, but Javascript interpolation. Thanks again!

Comment: Well what do you... something to learn. I never knew JS could do that. Thanks. I should read that up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the String interpolation and get it worked.

Here is what you could do.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let ulData = 2,
    liData = 4;

  document.querySelector(`div.grid ul[data="${ulData}"] li[data="${liData}"]`).classList.add("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <ul data="2">
    <li data="1">
      One
    </li>
    <li data="2">
      Two
    </li>
    <li data="3">
      Three
    </li>
    <li data="4">
      Four
    </li>
    <li data="5">
      Five
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```